# Ubuntu 15.04 Icon animations

Tags: icons, animations

Icon hover Animations?

I am wondering how I could enable it when I move my mouse on the unity launcher the icons could somewhat enlarge or show a glow or something. Just any type of feedback would be nice.

Thanks

Comment: I think that this is not possible in unity.